Bitbucket pipeline was stuck at step "[4/4] Building fresh packages..."
I'm using Bitbucket pipeline running on a repository with NodeJs 16.19.0, when run cmd "yarn --frozen-lockfile", it got stuck at step "[4/4] Building fresh packages..." and never done:
enter image description here
I have some other repositories on the same workspace with the same pipeline but they work, except this repository. This does not happen on my laptop, do you have any suggestions on this?
Thanks.
Tried with "yarn --frozen-lockfile --ignore-engines" or resolved errors but not work.

It worked after I downgraded "puppeteer" from "20.9.0" to "19.8.3"
